# Form values from dropdown list not passing

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I created a drop down list that has been populated by the database and now I'm having trouble retrieving the data. Normally, I would know how to retrieve the value of the drop down list if I had to manually name the data, but in this case, I'm not quite sure how I would name it.

Here is my current code:

```
   <h1>Generate Reports</h1>

     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/yiiFolder/index.php/create" method="post">
       <table>
             <tr>
                <td><strong>Materials</strong></td>
<?php
   mysql_connect('host', 'root', 'password');
   mysql_select_db ("db");
   $sql = "SELECT material_name FROM materials";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   echo "<td><select name='materials'>";

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['material_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row['material_name'] . "</option>";
        }

       echo "</select></td></tr> ";

       $sql2 = "SELECT location_name From locations";
       $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

?>


 <td><strong>Locations</strong></td>
   <?php
 echo "<td><select name='locations'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row2['location_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row2['location_name'] . "</option>";
        }   

echo "</select></td></tr>";

   ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button name="submit" type=submit>Generate</button></td>
                    </tr>
  </table>

 </form>


   <?php 

$material = $row['material_name'];
$locations = $row2['location_name'];
$generate = $_POST['submit'];

  if(isset($generate))
{
    echo $material;
    echo $locations;
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to capture value before the submit button is hit. Also, as Hanky pointed out you're using the wrong names while referring to select data. You should do this instead

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // this code will run after the button is clicked
{
    $material = $_POST['materials']; // and not material_name
    $locations = $_POST['locations']; // and not location_name
    echo $material;
    echo $locations;
}
```

PS: You're following a very unsecure way of developing a web application. At the very least you need to switch to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and always escape the data.

Comment: I understand that it's not secure. I'm just checking the basic logic before I actually integrate it within the Yii framework as I am very unfamiliar with how the whole drop down feature works in yii. Thanks for the help!